# VB6 UI thread and BrowerControl

Tags: vb6, webbrowser-control

Does a call to VB6 function from javascript hosted in browser control happen on the UI thread or in some background thread?

I have a VC++ component that is getting called from the VB function and this component was written with an assumption of being called from UI thread only.

Comment: Is it even possible to call a VB6 method from inside the browser control?

Comment: WebBrowser control exposes a "external" `objectforscripting`. Similar to the one described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Answer (score 0):

VB EXEs are only capable of running in a single thread, which is the principal, UI thread of the application. I can't see how a Javascript call can directly call into VB code. The only communication possible with VB code is via Events indirectly raised in either the WebBrowser control, or from MSHTML objects declare WithEvents. In this case, the very fact that you are writing code which responding to an event means that it is being raised in the UI thread.

Comment: WebBrowser control exposes a "external" `objectforscripting`. Similar to the one described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2

Answer (score 0):

ed.exe is a VB6 Automation exe and program.

```
Name                      ThreadCount
Ed.exe                    4
```

and it had 5 threads when first started.